# Python has multiple processes but only occupies one core

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve full CPU utilization for each Python process in a multiprocessing scenario, where each process is assigned to a separate CPU core.

1. When running the provided code on a Windows 11 system with a 16-core CPU, each core's utilization reaches 100%, which is the expected result.
2. However, after migrating the code to a 16-core Linux system, each Python process only utilizes an average of 6.25% (100/16) of the CPU. This indicates that each process is only using a single core, as on Linux, a process occupying 100% CPU typically means it is utilizing a single core.

Here is the code example I executed. I have tried both ProcessPoolExecutor and Pool.

```py
# executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_worker)
    pool = Pool(processes=max_worker)
    # futures = []
    # results = []
    args = []
    for worker in range(max_worker):
        if worker == max_worker - 1:
            _data = data.iloc[worker * count:]
        else:
            _data = data.iloc[worker * count: worker * count + count]
        args.append((config_path, _data))
        # future = executor.submit(func, config_path, _data)
        # futures.append(future)
    # for future in futures:
    #     result = future.result()
    #     results.append(result)
    results = pool.starmap(func, args)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYlao.png

I'm unsure about the cause of this issue and would appreciate assistance in achieving full CPU utilization for each Python process. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @KostasNitaf how does that answer the question? The OP is using multiprocessing

Comment: How are you determining the processor utilization on Windows? How are you doing it on Linux?

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: The behaviour will be largely dependent on what *func()* does